# Why is basic_string_view not limited to character types?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++23

Browsing [twitter](https://twitter.com/vzverovich/status/1475856164810223617) I found this example of C++23 code.

This is my [adaptation](https://godbolt.org/z/4MbWeGGqE) of it, to make more obvious what I am interested about(I do not care about dangling problems mentioned in replies).

```
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


int main() {
    std::vector v{84.72};
    std::basic_string_view sv = v;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(sv), std::basic_string_view<double>>);
    const auto val = *std::begin(sv);
    std::cout << val;
}
```

My question is why isn't there some requires/concept constraint on the `basic_string_view` to make it work only with char*ish* types, so `basic_string_view<double>` in this example would not compile?

Comment: Why do you think there should be one? If, for some reason, someone wants to use this template, for some odd reason, this way, what problem would that create?

Comment: Unrelated: It's not limited to C++23. `std::basic_string_view<double> sv(v.data(), v.size());` would work in C++17 and later.

Comment: Which are is `char`ish types?

Comment: Is even legal to use `double` as a char type for `std::basic_string` or `std::basic_string_view`? Wouldn't `std::char_traits<double>` be required?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  because we have string/vector split in old C++ (based on suggested usage) I expected that new C++ would want to enforce that for basic_string_view/span...

Comment: @DanielLangr code compiles in C++23, IDK why.

Comment: @DanielLangr Looking at the string_view proposal (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3762.html) it does seem it really is intended for char types and the check should IMO be there. The proposal even mentions: char_traits  in contiguous_range<charT>

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl That it compiles doesn't mean its correct ;) It might even work...

Comment: @Jarod42 hand waving.. more hand waving... :) I would expect all the builtin char types, including unicode ones maybe...(problem is that then string_view size is nonsense, since it is no "strlen" but like "byteslen"

Comment: @DanielLangr I just checked, as expected based on twitter discussion, they have added range constructor to std::string_view https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view (6)

Comment: This is not a question about C++23 `basic_string_view`, but a old question about why [we can write `basic_string<double>` in C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/fe6z6oz4s).

Comment: @康桓瑋 well, it is *possible* (I have no idea) that fixing basic_string would break much more code than fixing basic_string_view. And I think before it would have been tricky to enforce concept checks with ton of enable_if... Also in C++23 AFAIK string has no range ctor, only string_view... So you are right mostly I think, but I still think they are not same thing.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl. There is nothing that needs to be "fixed". The `basic_string`'s  template parameter reserved for non-character types is [sometimes valuable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDJImePyftY&t=153s&ab_channel=CppCon).

Comment: How would you define a "charish" type?

Comment: @Sean as I replied to Jarod42 I would define it to be all built in char types, except maybe unicode...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is a `char`-like type:

```cpp
struct Char {
    char c;
    Char() : c{} {}
    Char(char c) : c{c} {}
};
```

Why shouldn't it work? Indeed it does

```cpp
std::basic_string<Char> str{'a', 'b'}; // OK
std::cout << str[0].c << std::endl; // prints a
std::cout << str.length() << std::endl; // prints 2
```

And what makes that class special with respect to, say, this?

```
struct Char {
    int c;
    Char() : c{} {}
    Char(int c) : c{c} {}
};
```

Nothing, except our decision that `char` is a character and `int` is not. (And that's exactly the reason why I had to write `std::cout << str[0].c` and couldn't write `std::cout << str` or `std::cout << str[0]`, because `<<` is overloaded for `char`s and maybe something else, but certainly not for my own types.)

So the bottom line, as implied by some comments, is a counter-question:

> How would you define a "charish" type?

which I would rephrase as

> Can we encode the definiton of "sequence of `char`-like objects" in a concept?

which leads in turn to another question:

> What operations can you do **only** on a "sequence of `char`-like objects" that you can't do on **all** "sequences of non-`char`-like objects"?

I can't think of one.

So if you wanted to enforce the constraint you mention, you would end up explicitly listing  `char`, `wchar`, and all the others in some SFINAE thing.

And then you couldn't use it with any other type.

Comment: Now we are getting into the me feels instead of something that can be objectively judged, but. I feel this is a wrong question "What operations can you do only on char-like objects ". I would ask what operations you can do on sequence of char like objects. Then things become a bit easier, e.g.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/starts_with although you can do abominations like this: https://godbolt.org/z/scc6bPc61

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, why would that be an abomination? (regarding sequence of Ts vs T, I've corrected the text of my answer). I mean, it is an abomonation only in view of the fact that `char` is a character and `double` is not. But again, that is encoded simply in the _name_ of the type. Nowhere else.

Comment: Like I said this is my personal feeling. I would never use string/string_view for generic container purposes. As for operations: printing them without a separator seems like a reasonable suggestion, e.g printed vector of char is [a,b,c] or {a,b,c}, printed string is abc. Another one would be using it as input to regex... but again this is just my opinion, I dont want to sound like a fanatic warrior in strong types holly war. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, no worries, I'm not making a war. But your comments trigger thoughts, which I share. For instance you mentioned regex. Regex engines don't work because `a` is character, but just because it can be checked for equality with other things of the same type, maybe it belongs to an equivalence class together with`à`, ... There's no reason, in principle, why regex shouldn't work with my `Char` type. Or with a type they'll invent tomorrow, named `char128_t`. I'm just suggesting that maybe all that makes `char` a character type is that it belongs to a list of types we call characters.

Comment: Well this is going a bit offtopic, but although I agree partially there are plenty of specific regex stuff that only makes sense for chars, not floats or set::set<int>, e.g. \w \s ... Obviously regex state machines being build do not care about the fact that humans give special meaning to stuff like word or space, but regex API does. So there would need to be a way to tell regex what \w is for your type...